# ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rbenv, gemset, rbenv-gemset

I have install rbev

```
rbenv version
2.0.0-p247 (set by /Users/amritdeepdhungana/.rbenv/version)
```

, ruby

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]\
```

and rails

```
rails -v
Rails 4.0.1
```

I have create new project and bundle it. But I get this problem

```
Installing rake (10.1.1)
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/build_info/rake-10.1.1.info
An error occurred while installing rake (10.1.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.1.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

After that, I have install rake gem but again I got error

```
gem install rake -v '10.1.1'
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rake' (= 10.1.1), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - too many connection resets (https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: rake
```

How can I set the permission while install any gem package ?

Comment: did you install ruby as root or with `sudo`??

Answer (score 0):

Like @bjhaid said, you're trying to install these gems into your system Ruby.

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/build_info/rake-10.1.1.info
```

Ruby 2.0.0p247 is bundled w/Mavericks.  Specifically:

```
$ /usr/bin/ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
```

My self-built (rvm) version is has a slightly different version string:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
```

To find out which ruby is actually being used, try `which ruby`.  Make sure you've properly installed rbenv, and installed a new local Ruby.

Comment: which ruby
/Users/amritdeepdhungana/.rbenv/shims/ruby

ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin13.0.0]

Answer (score 0):

It almost looks like you haven't set your PATH up correctly, but your answer to Nick Veys' question doesn't look like it. I would surmise that you haven't installed any ruby under `rbenv` yet. What does `rbenv versions` look like?